# Выполнение внешнего JS, добавленного с помощью .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var banner='<script src="http://domen.zona/path/script.js"><\/script>';
document.getElementById("ad").innerHTML = banner;
```

Код в диве с ID="ad" появляется, но содержимое файла не выполняется (даже сам файл не загружается).

Дополнительные библиотеки типа JQuery не используются.

В переменной "banner" содержится код баннеров, он может быть разный (картинки в виде HTML, скрипты прямо в коде, внешние скрипты и комбинации всего этого), парсить и создавать элементы будет сложно. Проблема осталась только со внешними файлами. Внутренний JavaScript выполняется так:

```
var scripts = document.getElementById("ad").getElementsByTagName("script");
var script;
for (var i = 0; script = scripts[i]; i++)
{
   eval(script.innerHTML); 
}
```

Что можно придумать, чтобы содержимое script.js выполнилось?

Comment: @FiwaProlje, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Я уже на стороне сервера сделал (из внешнего файла в код страницы).

Answer (score 1):

```
Используй вот эту функцию:
function include(file) //ссылка на файл
{
    var a = document.createElement("script");
    a.src = file;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.onload = function() 
    {
        alert("Файл : '" +file+"' успешно подключен");
    }
};
```